# Can I run a single .js file in Node.js and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Node.js/Express project, and now I want to test one single file(one function) of it.

For now, the only way I know to do this is to call this function in the `index.js` file, and after issuing `npm run dev` all functions in the file will be run.

However, now I only want to test one single function, so I think that approach is not suitable.

So could anyone teach me how to run a single file/function in Node.js?

Thanks. The function/file I want to run is as below, which is a Reddit scraper.

```
const snoowrap = require("snoowrap");

async function redditCrawler(companyName, numOfMentionsToObtain) {
  const scraper = new snoowrap({
    userAgent: process.env.Reddit_userAgent,
    clientId: process.env.Reddit_clientId,
    clientSecret: process.env.Reddit_clientSecret,
    refreshToken: process.env.Reddit_refreshToken,
  });

  const subreddit = await scraper.getSubreddit("all");
  const topPosts = await subreddit.getHot({
    time: "all",
    limit: numOfMentionsToObtain,
  });

  let data = [];

  topPosts.forEach((post) => {
    // If a post doesn't have any content, just ignore it.
    if (post.title.includes(companyName) && post.selftext) {
      // If a post doesn't have a thumbnail picture, just use Reddit's logo.
      if (post.thumbnail.substr(0, 8) !== "https://") {
        post.thumbnail = "/imgs/reddit_icon.png";
      }
      data.push({
        image: post.thumbnail,
        title: post.title,
        popularity: post.score,
        content: post.selftext,
        date: post.created, // In Unix time format(in milisecond).
        platform: "Reddit",
      });
    }
  });

  return data;
}

module.exports = redditCrawler;
```

Comment: you could write a task in npm package that looks something like this `node -e 'require("./file-name").fn()'`

Comment: tried `node <filename>` ?

Comment: Create a file called `reddit-crawler-test.js` and `require` your `redditCrawler` function inside it, then call it with whatever parameters you want, and finally run `node reddit-crawler-test.js` in the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just run it from node directly via `node yourFile.js`

You would just need to actually call the function though so you'd want to stick `redditCrawler();` at the bottom of your file and potentially remove `module.exports`